# Are all GUI elements in qtcreator able to be moved around by the user? Or only some?

Tags: eclipse, qt, ide, qt-creator

Specifically:

Can you drag "Compile Output" or "projects" to be at a different location than they are by default?

---

More generally:

I am very accustomed to using Eclipse IDE... where every item viewed in the default perspective can be dragged... put into a tabbed view... etc. For now I have to use qtcreator... and I can't figure out how to drag/move each GUI item. (It would help me if your answer compares to Eclipse IDE when talking about qtcreator because I understand Eclipse IDE much better.)

**Are all qtcreator GUI elements able to be user draggable and customized like in Eclipse IDE in a UNIFORM manner?**

**Or are only some of the GUI elements in qtcreator able to be user draggable?**

(if yes for any question, please describe how to do so.)

Comment: EXAMPLE: when in the debug mode, there are "breakpoints", "threads", and other GUI widgets. In a specific... "window" or "abstract section" or "abstract horizontal 'Debugging' split" of the GUI I can drag/drop these GUI widgets and get a nice tabbed view. But If I want to drag the "Threads" widget into the section that holds the "compiler output"... I can't do that.

Comment: To my knowledge... it seems like the section holding the "projects", "text editor", and "compiler output" are not draggable...

Comment: maybe I am just not informed about how to drag/drop these various IDE widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot drag / drop.

Some windows can be split, you can maximize the main window etc.

You can change what is being shown at the bottom by clicking buttons, but I've never seen a way to move screen real estate around, resize etc.